# Ignore print statements when try catch exception

Tags: python, exception, try-except

I have this simple `try-except` code:

```
self.tf.router.EchoProg(state=1)
try:
    print "\tCheckTestFirmwareCommunication_SetPort: "  
    print self.tf.DUT.CheckTestFirmwareCommunication_SetPort()
except NoResponseException, e:
    print "\tCheckTestFirmwareCommunication_SetPort: ", repr(e)
self.tf.router.EchoProg(state=0)
```

**Output with Exception:**

> CheckTestFirmwareCommunication_SetPort:
>   CheckTestFirmwareCommunication_SetPort: 
>   DD_NoResponseException()

**Questions:**

1. Can someone explain why i still see the print statements even if i get an exception?
2. Is it possible to ignore print statements if the `try-except` catch an exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the *second* `print` line that throws the exception:

```
print self.tf.DUT.CheckTestFirmwareCommunication_SetPort()
```

The first `print` line did not and was executed.

Python executes each statement within the `try` suite, and only when one throws an exception, is execution aborted and transfers to the `except` block. If you don't want the first `print` statement to execute when `CheckTestFirmwareCommunication_SetPort` throws an exception, *call that method first*:

```
self.tf.router.EchoProg(state=1)
try:
    port = self.tf.DUT.CheckTestFirmwareCommunication_SetPort()
    print "\tCheckTestFirmwareCommunication_SetPort: "  
    print port
except NoResponseException, e:
    print "\tCheckTestFirmwareCommunication_SetPort: ", repr(e)
self.tf.router.EchoProg(state=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The first `print` statement is executed before the exception occurs, hence they are printed.

The exception here is raised by `self.tf.DUT.CheckTestFirmwareCommunication_SetPort()`. You can move the print statements below it, so that it'll be printed when the first line is successfully executed.

```
try:
    print self.tf.DUT.CheckTestFirmwareCommunication_SetPort()
    print "\tCheckTestFirmwareCommunication_SetPort: "  
except NoResponseException, e:
    print "\tCheckTestFirmwareCommunication_SetPort: ", repr(e)
```

Comment: by changing the code like that, the output will not be as intended. the `port` will be printed before the string `"\tCheckTestFirmwareCommunication_SetPort: "`

Comment: @RaydelMiranda Yes that's true. I was not aware that the order of print statements is important.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that exception is raised by the line:

```
print self.tf.DUT.CheckTestFirmwareCommunication_SetPort()
```

so the line:

```
print "\tCheckTestFirmwareCommunication_SetPort: "
```

always will by executed.

to avoid that change your code to:

```
self.tf.router.EchoProg(state=1)
try:

    port =  self.tf.DUT.CheckTestFirmwareCommunication_SetPort()
except NoResponseException, e:
    print "\tCheckTestFirmwareCommunication_SetPort: ", repr(e)
else:
    print "\tCheckTestFirmwareCommunication_SetPort: ", port  
self.tf.router.EchoProg(state=0)
```